# Theme the "save" button in a profile page, on a Drupal 6 installation?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

How do you theme the "save" button in the profile page (user/uid), on a Drupal 6 installation?
I´ve tried and when I try to theme it, it theme all "save" buttons on the site.

Thanks!!

Rosamunda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try embedding the CSS code in a new CSS file and add it to this page specifically through template_preprocess_page in template.php

```
function template_preprocess_page(&$variables)
{
    if(arg(0) == "user" && is_numeric(arg(1)) && is_null(arg(2)))
    {
        drupal_add_css('PATH_TO_CSS_FILE');
    }
}
```

Don't forget to replace the word "template" in the function name, with your theme's machine name. For example "**bartik**_prerocess_page"

more info about template_preprocess_page(), here: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7

Hope this helps

Muhammad